# Stacking multiple Text elements in a single Drag and Drop element using z-index property

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have twelve arguments that i am trying to stack in no particular order on one Drag and drop element.The end user should be able to drag these texts and drop them in a matching element. The problem is the overlapping texts seem to have warped on each other hence the various titles to be dragged from the stack are no longer clearly visible. Does anyone know how to stack texts using z-index property? I have attached an image.[image: the 12 Text elements as stacked in a single Drag and Drop element]

Here is my code

```css
#argumente1,
#argumente2,
#argumente3,
#argumente4,
#argumente5,
#argumente6,
#argumente7,
#argumente8,
#argumente9,
#argumente10,
#argumente11,
#argumente12{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:500px;
    width:280px;  
    height:60px;
    
}

#argumente1{
    z-index: 12;
}

#argumente2{
    z-index: 11;
}

/*goes on until all twelve id's are defined*/
```

```html
<div class="ansicht">
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Firt argument</div>
           <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">second argument</div>
           <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Third of twelve arguments</div>
</div>
```

while at it please also help me look at the corresponding Javascript that is also not responsive

```js
function dragstart_handler(ev){
      //add elements id to the data transfer object
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain",ev.target.id);
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {
    // Get element by id 
   const element = document.querySelectorAll ("#argumente1,#argumente2,#argumente3,#argumente4,#argumente5,#argumente6,#argumente7,#argumente8,#argumente9,#argumente10,#argumente11,#argumente12");
    // Add on drag start event listener
   element.addEventListener("dragstart",dragstart_handler);
});

function dragstart_handler(ev){
        //Add drag data
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", ev.target.innerText);
}

function dragover_handler(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
}

function drop_handler(ev){
    ev.preventDefault()
    // Get the id of the target and add the moved element to the target's DOM
    const data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data))
}
```

Comment: you should remove the position from argument

Comment: give them a background-color, so the top one will be clearly readable, i guess ...

Comment: @MehediHasanSiam that removes the elements from the stack and therefore does not serve the intended purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Probably not what you looked for, but for infos and shorter CSS declaration*

- You may ommit the `z-index` property reset if you use the natural stacking context, which puts the last one on top.
- You can also , avoid `position` if you use a `grid` and stack them inside the same grid cell:

exmple with the background-color, so you can pick them one after the other

```js
var dragged;

  /* events fired on the draggable target */
  document.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {

  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
      // store a ref. on the dragged elem
      dragged = event.target;
      // make it half transparent
      event.target.style.opacity = .5;
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragend", function( event ) {
      // reset the transparency
      event.target.style.opacity = "";
  }, false);

  /* events fired on the drop targets */
  document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
      // prevent default to allow drop
      event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragenter", function( event ) {
      // highlight potential drop target when the draggable element enters it
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "purple";
      }

  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragleave", function( event ) {
      // reset background of potential drop target when the draggable element leaves it
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "";
      }

  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
      // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
      event.preventDefault();
      // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "";
          dragged.parentNode.removeChild( dragged );
          event.target.appendChild( dragged );
      }
    
  }, false);
```

```css
.b_dotted {
  width: 280px;
  height: 60px;
  background: white;
  border: solid;
  grid-row: 1;/* first row*/
  grid-column: -1;/* last cell if number of column is unknown */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ansicht {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
  justify-content: end;
  border: double;
}

.bis {
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  /* reset to a single col */
  width: max-content;
  float: right;
  /* ?? useful ? */
}
```

```html
<div class="ansicht">
  Is that container use for something else ? , if no, remove that text and the grid-template-columns rule from the CSS;
  <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente43"draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">fourth of twelve arguments</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente3"draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">Third of twelve arguments</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente2"draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">second argument</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente1"draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">Firt argument</div>
</div>
    <div class="dropzone">
    Dropzone:
    </div>
<p>similar approach from a single cell and hooked and floated to the right side.</p>
<div class="ansicht bis">
  <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente43"draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">fourth of twelve arguments</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente3"draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">Third of twelve arguments</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente2"draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">second argument</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente1"draggable="true" ondragstart="event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)">Firt argument</div>
</div>
```

Comment: From the Javascript end. I have 4 different 'dropzones' that need to be matched with the corresponding arguments. Each 'dropzone' has atleast 3 right arguments. And there needs to be an alert of sorts telling the user that they have matched correctly.

Comment: @S.Okumu could you share your html / dropzone to see what can be done to filter each of them to match with draggable items ? a classname would probably do the job.

Comment: i have shared it as edit. Don't know if that is allowed in this community but have a look. Please note the 'dropzone' className only works while declared inside the img tags.

Comment: it seems that will take time before you are able to see my Html. Please check out the link for the new question i put up. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64056899/drag-and-drop-elements-with-different-ids-into-their-corresponding-dropzones

Answer (score 0):

as you used `position: absolute;` to all argument and it's mandatory, that's why it's overlapping among themselves. you should fix all the arguments position by defining.

```css
#argumente1,
#argumente2,
#argumente3,
#argumente4,
#argumente5,
#argumente6,
#argumente7,
#argumente8,
#argumente9,
#argumente10,
#argumente11,
#argumente12{
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:500px;
    width:280px;  
    height:60px;
    
}

#argumente1{
    z-index: 12;
}

#argumente2{
    z-index: 11;
    top: 24px;
}
#argumente3{
        top: 43px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ansicht">
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Firt argument</div>
           <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">second argument</div>
           <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Third of twelve arguments</div>
</div>
```