# Drag and drop elements with different id's into their corresponding dropzones

Tags: javascript, html

I have twelve arguments with different id's that i'd like to drag and drop into their corresponding clouds. Each of the four clouds has atleast three corresponding arguments. Should the wrong argument be dropped in the wrong cloud then there should be an error message displayed and the wrong argument sent back to the initial placeholder. I have so far succeeded in coding the drag and drop but i can't seem to direct the draggables to their intended dropzones owing to the number of id's involved. I would appreciate any help.

Here is my html and javascript code

```css
   
var dragged;

  /* events fired on the draggable target */
  document.addEventListener("drag", function( event ) {

  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragstart", function( event ) {
      // store a ref. on the dragged elem
      dragged = event.target;
      // make it half transparent
      event.target.style.opacity = .5;
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragend", function( event ) {
      // reset the transparency
      event.target.style.opacity = "";
  }, false);

  /* events fired on the drop targets */
  document.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
      // prevent default to allow drop
      event.preventDefault();
  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragenter", function( event ) {
      // highlight potential drop target when the draggable element enters it
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "purple";
      }

  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("dragleave", function( event ) {
      // reset background of potential drop target when the draggable element leaves it
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "";
      }

  }, false);

  document.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
      // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
      event.preventDefault();
      // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
      if ( event.target.className == "dropzone" ) {
          event.target.style.background = "";
          dragged.parentNode.removeChild( dragged );
          event.target.appendChild( dragged );
      }
    
  }, false);
```

```html
<div class="ansicht">
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Was ist mit</div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Individualismus</div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Der Trittbettfahrer-Vorwand</div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Technologischer Optimismus </div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Alles Gerede, wenig Handlung</div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente6" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Lösungskonzept Fossile Energieträger</div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente7" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Keine Peitsche, nur Zuckerbrot </div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente8" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Berufung auf Soziale Gerechtigkeit </div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente9" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Perfektionismus</div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente10" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Berufung auf Wohlstand </div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente11" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Der Untergang</div>
            <div class="b_dotted" id="argumente12" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Veränderung ist unmöglich</div>
        </div>
        <div id="grenze">
            <img class="dropzone" id="cloud1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/wolke1.png">
            <img class="dropzone" id="cloud2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/wolke2.png">
            <img class="dropzone" id="cloud3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/wolke3.png">
            <img class="dropzone" id="cloud4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/wolke4.png"> 
        </div>
```

Comment: so you want to automatically get appended to valid parent if they are dragged to drop zone instead of they going back to start position? which property you are using to determine which draggable belongs to which image(dropzone)?

Comment: @sandeepjoshi appended to valid parent, yes. Otherwise take it back to start position. I was thinking this can be made possible using the id's. for example #argument1 to #wolke1 and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so if I understood correctly what you wanted was to drag element to `dropzone` and allow operation if some condition is passed, else return the element from where we started dragging it.

What I did in below snippet is I gave each `div` an `attribute` called `group` which you can access using `element.attributes.group.value` and only allowing the detach logic to trigger if the dragged element has that group number. hope this will give you idea to implement what you are trying to achieve.

also if you define function for `ondrop` `ondrag` etc then you have to define them as function to avoid getting console error as HTML will look for these function in JS.

```js
var dragged;

function allowDrop(event) {}
/* events fired on the draggable target */
function drag(event) {

}

document.addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
  // store a ref. on the dragged elem
  dragged = event.target;
  // make it half transparent
  event.target.style.opacity = 0.5;
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragend", function(event) {
  // reset the transparency
  event.target.style.opacity = "";
}, false);

/* events fired on the drop targets */
document.addEventListener("dragover", function(event) {
  // prevent default to allow drop
  event.preventDefault();
}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragenter", function(event) {
  // highlight potential drop target when the draggable element enters it
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "purple";
  }

}, false);

document.addEventListener("dragleave", function(event) {
  // reset background of potential drop target when the draggable element leaves it
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
    event.target.style.background = "";
  }

}, false);

function drop(event) {
  // prevent default action (open as link for some elements)
  event.preventDefault();
  // move dragged elem to the selected drop target
  //check if the target is dropzone and dragged element have the required group value if yes allow append child else dont do anything just reset color and opacity
  debugger;
  if (event.target.className == "dropzone" && dragged.attributes.group.value == event.target.attributes.group.value) {
    event.target.style.background = "";
    dragged.parentNode.removeChild(dragged);
    event.target.appendChild(dragged);
    //you may wanna comment success message as these may be annoying
  } else {
    if (event.target.className == "dropzone") {
      event.target.style.background = "";
    }
    dragged.style.opacity = 0.5;
    alert('please drop the item to section : '+dragged.attributes.group.value)
  }



}
```

```html
<div class="ansicht">
  <div class="b_dotted" group="1" id="argumente1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Was ist mit</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="2" id="argumente2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Individualismus</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="3" id="argumente3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Der Trittbettfahrer-Vorwand</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="4" id="argumente4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Technologischer Optimismus </div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="1" id="argumente5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Alles Gerede, wenig Handlung</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="2" id="argumente6" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Lösungskonzept Fossile Energieträger</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="3" id="argumente7" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Keine Peitsche, nur Zuckerbrot </div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="4" id="argumente8" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Berufung auf Soziale Gerechtigkeit </div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="1" id="argumente9" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Perfektionismus</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="2" id="argumente10" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Berufung auf Wohlstand </div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="3" id="argumente11" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Der Untergang</div>
  <div class="b_dotted" group="4" id="argumente12" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Veränderung ist unmöglich</div>
</div>
<div id="grenze">
  <img class="dropzone" group="1" id="wolke1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/wolke1.png">
  <img class="dropzone" group="2" id="wolke2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/wolke2.png">
  <img class="dropzone" group="3" id="wolke3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/wolke3.png">
  <img class="dropzone" group="4" id="wolke4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" src="img/wolke4.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi I have made slight modification so now you have drag and drop the item to the correct group hope this helps

Comment: The alert messages are not triggering. Am still able to drop the wrong arguments in the wrong dropzones as it is. And that also means the elements are not automatically dragged back to the starting point when the argument does not match.

Comment: you are talking about my code snippet? bcoz i tried and i am able to drop the right argument in the correct dropzone. if i mismatch i am getting alert saying "please drop the item to section : 4" (correct section it should go)